# RABBITMQ web access to MANAGEMENT plugin: cannot access it from remote computer

Tags: apache2, rabbitmq

I am following the guidelines to implement the [RABBITMQ 
 MANAGEMENT PLUGIN](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) on a remote server.

I launched `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. It worked and now when I launch`rabbitmq-plugins list`, it shows in the list:

> [E ] rabbitmq_management               3.5.7

But if I try to access the server with my local brower with [IP ADDRESS]:15672. The request goes in timeout. Also it seems that I do what is explain in the documentation:

> The Web UI is located at: http://server-name:15672/

In the doc it doesn't specify to set a `conf` in `/etc/apache2/site-available/` and I would not know which path to assign to the "DocumentRoot", but I thought `apache2` should be listening to port 15672 for that to work, so I edited:
`/etc/apache2/port.conf` and added: `Listen 15672` below the `Listen 80` lign. **It seems to have created a conflict** so I removed the lign `Listen 15672` from `/etc/apache2/port.conf`.

I did:
 `service apache2 reload`, `service apache2 restart`, `service rabbitmq-server restart`

If I launch a `sudo lsof -i -n -P`, to list the Application Name, PID, User, IP version, Device ID and the Node with Port Name, it seems good:

> beam     13649 rabbitmq   18u  IPv6 3280502      0t0  TCP *:5672 (LISTEN)
>   beam     13649 rabbitmq   19u  IPv4 3280505      0t0  TCP *:15672 (LISTEN)

Do you have any recommendation?

SOME UDPATES:
I realised I could access it using the [ DNS name ]:15672 on some of my machine (not all of them, even after cache clean of the browser on the machine that goes in timeout), also that [ DNS name ] should be, according to what I want, only accessible from the PORT 80 ([see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900402/apache2-etc-apache2-sites-available-conf-name-conf-servername-associated-to)).

Answer (score 0):

I found why:

The local WIFI network does not seems to have 15672 PORT opened for outgoing request.